# TensorFlow beginner use estimator for prediction after running experiment

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

I am following this guide by Google (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/tensorflow/d_experiment.ipynb) to build a simple linear regression model.

In the notebook it has used the `Experiment` class and `learn_runner` (a class that I cannot find any documentation) to train up the model. I am now trying to use the model for prediction. I tried the following but i got an error. Would you please let me know the correct way to do it? Thanks.

**Code added to the bottom:**

```
# load the saved model
estimator = tflearn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols, model_dir='taxi_trained')
estimator.predict(input_fn=get_test)
```

**Error got:**

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_is_chief': True, '_model_dir': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x00000218611630F0>, '_master': '', '_task_id': 0, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_evaluation_master': '', '_environment': 'local', '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1
}
, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_task_type': None, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_save_summary_steps': 100}
WARNING:tensorflow:From c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:335: calling LinearRegressor.predict (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.linear) with outputs=None is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-01.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to predict_scores, or set `outputs` argument.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7f1903437174> in <module>()
      1 with tf.Session() as sess:
      2     estimator = tflearn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols, model_dir='taxi_trained')
----> 3     estimator.predict(input_fn=get_test)

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    333               _call_location(), decorator_utils.get_qualified_name(func),
    334               func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, date, instructions)
--> 335       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    336     new_func.__doc__ = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(
    337         func.__doc__, date, instructions)

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    333               _call_location(), decorator_utils.get_qualified_name(func),
    334               func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, date, instructions)
--> 335       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    336     new_func.__doc__ = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(
    337         func.__doc__, date, instructions)

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\linear.py in predict(self, x, input_fn, batch_size, outputs, as_iterable)
    755           input_fn=input_fn,
    756           batch_size=batch_size,
--> 757           as_iterable=as_iterable)
    758     return super(LinearRegressor, self).predict(
    759         x=x,

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    333               _call_location(), decorator_utils.get_qualified_name(func),
    334               func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, date, instructions)
--> 335       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    336     new_func.__doc__ = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(
    337         func.__doc__, date, instructions)

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\linear.py in predict_scores(self, x, input_fn, batch_size, as_iterable)
    790         batch_size=batch_size,
    791         outputs=[key],
--> 792         as_iterable=as_iterable)
    793     if as_iterable:
    794       return _as_iterable(preds, output=key)

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    279             _call_location(), decorator_utils.get_qualified_name(func),
    280             func.__module__, arg_name, date, instructions)
--> 281       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    282     new_func.__doc__ = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(
    283         func.__doc__, date, instructions)

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py in predict(self, x, input_fn, batch_size, outputs, as_iterable)
    563         feed_fn=feed_fn,
    564         outputs=outputs,
--> 565         as_iterable=as_iterable)
    566 
    567   def get_variable_value(self, name):

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py in _infer_model(self, input_fn, feed_fn, outputs, as_iterable, iterate_batches)
    855       contrib_framework.create_global_step(g)
    856       features = self._get_features_from_input_fn(input_fn)
--> 857       infer_ops = self._get_predict_ops(features)
    858       predictions = self._filter_predictions(infer_ops.predictions, outputs)
    859       mon_sess = monitored_session.MonitoredSession(

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py in _get_predict_ops(self, features)
   1186     labels = tensor_signature.create_placeholders_from_signatures(
   1187         self._labels_info)
-> 1188     return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.INFER)
   1189 
   1190   def export_savedmodel(

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode)
   1101     if 'model_dir' in model_fn_args:
   1102       kwargs['model_dir'] = self.model_dir
-> 1103     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
   1104 
   1105     if isinstance(model_fn_results, model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps):

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\linear.py in _linear_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params, config)
    159             num_outputs=head.logits_dimension,
    160             weight_collections=[parent_scope],
--> 161             scope=scope)
    162 
    163     def _train_op_fn(loss):

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\layers\feature_column_ops.py in weighted_sum_from_feature_columns(columns_to_tensors, feature_columns, num_outputs, weight_collections, trainable, scope)
    529     # pylint: disable=protected-access
    530     for column in sorted(set(feature_columns), key=lambda x: x.key):
--> 531       transformed_tensor = transformer.transform(column)
    532       try:
    533         embedding_lookup_arguments = column._wide_embedding_lookup_arguments(

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\layers\feature_column_ops.py in transform(self, feature_column)
    880       return self._columns_to_tensors[feature_column]
    881 
--> 882     feature_column.insert_transformed_feature(self._columns_to_tensors)
    883 
    884     if feature_column not in self._columns_to_tensors:

c:\users\tommy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\layers\feature_column.py in insert_transformed_feature(self, columns_to_tensors)
   1406     """
   1407     # Transform the input tensor according to the normalizer function.
-> 1408     input_tensor = self._normalized_input_tensor(columns_to_tensors[self.name])
   1409     columns_to_tensors[self] = math_ops.to_float(input_tensor)
   1410 

KeyError: 'dropofflat'
```

I am using TensorFlow 1.1 with Python 3.5 on Windows 10. GPU enabled.